# PHP: sorting/searching data that has 2 keys (or an array of arrays by a sub-array key)?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, search, multidimensional-array

I've hit this a few times and never found the best way to tackle it. It's easiest to illustrate with a concrete example. Sample data:

```
product_id     display_name         display_order
----------     ------------         -------------
"samgal3"      "Samsung Galaxy 3"        0
"motorazrh"    "Motorola Razr HD"        1
"iphone5"      "Apple iphone 5"          2

etc
```

The actual arrays are often small (<20 items), though not always, and have guaranteed unique keys/values. Each item has a unique sort key (order it's listed in, for html table/enumeration), a unique internal key (for item lookup), and a human-readable display name.

Typically I hit this issue when a list of options is used on a form. The same data is used both to populate dropdown boxes on forms, and also to validate the submitted $GET/POST data. When generating the form, it needs to be enumerated/listed in 'sort' order to create the SELECT box options in order. When a form is submitted it needs to be searchable by 'product_id' (to validate "...&action=view&product_id=elephant..." is a product in the list).

If I use 'sort'=>array(other data) as the key, then displaying by 'sort' is easy but searching within $data[***]['product_id'] is hard *(ie identify $KEY if it exists, having $data[$KEY]['product_id'] == 'htcvox')*. If I use 'product_id'=>array(other data) as the key then searching whether 'samgal3' is in the array and finding its data is easy but there's no simple way to walk/enumerate the array by 'sort' to create the form.

I guess I can do a custom search/sort where the search/sort key for any member $i in $data is $i['product_id'] or $i['sort'] but it's clumsy and I've never done it before. Simplicity counts as the code will be open source.

I'm expecting to code the data as an array of arrays, like this:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array('product_id'=>'samgal3',   'display_name' => 'Samsung Galaxy 3'),
    1 => array('product_id'=>'motorazrh', 'display_name' => 'Motorola Razr HD'),
    ...
```

or

```
$data = array(
    'samgal3'   => array('sort'=>0, 'display_name' => 'Samsung Galaxy 3'),
    'motorazrh' => array('sort'=>1, 'display_name' => 'Motorola Razr HD'),
    ...
```

Put the same problem differently, given an 2D array of arrays: **$data = array(array1, array2, array3, ....);** where all of array1, array2, array3, ... contain a key/field with a fixed name, is there an easy way to search/sort the nested arrays on $ARRAY[****]['named_field']?

Comment: I would use the product id as the key and sort it before creating the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is essentially multiple indexes into a single array, just like you would have multiple indexes on a single table in a relational database. (Sorting is a separate but related concern.)

Let's start with this basic data structure, a simple set of arrays with no particular importance attached to the keys:

```
$data = array(
    array('display_order'=> 0, 'product_id'=>'samgal3',   'display_name' => 'Samsung Galaxy 3'),
    array('display_order'=> 1, 'product_id'=>'motorazrh', 'display_name' => 'Motorola Razr HD'),
    array('display_order'=> 2, 'product_id'=>'a', 'display_name' => 'a'),
    array('display_order'=> 3, 'product_id'=>'c', 'display_name' => 'c'),
    array('display_order'=> 4, 'product_id'=>'d', 'display_name' => 'd'),
    array('display_order'=> 5, 'product_id'=>'b', 'display_name' => 'b'),
    array('display_order'=> 6, 'product_id'=>'q', 'display_name' => 'q'),
    array('display_order'=> 7, 'product_id'=>'f', 'display_name' => 'f'),
);
```

You can create an explicit index easily and then use it to get `$data` items:

```
$product_id_idx = array_flip(array_map(function($item){return $item['product_id'];}, $data));
$samgal3_array = $data[$product_id_idx['samgal3']]; // same as $data[0]
```

For sorting you can use the oft-forgotten [`array_multisort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).  Look at example 3 in the documentation. The trick is to create arrays to sort on and include the full data set as the last argument. For example:

```
array_multisort(array_keys($product_id_idx), SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $data);
```

`$data` is now sorted by product key. The original numeric array keys of `$data` are lost, however, which means our `$product_id_idx` is not usable anymore. Thus it's best to sort a *copy* of the data array if you want to keep using your indexes.

We can combine both these approaches into a single class to preserve our sanity:

```
class MultiIndex {

    protected $array;
    protected $indexes = array();
    protected $indexdefs = array();

    function __construct($array, $indexdefs)
    {
        $this->array = $array;
        $this->indexdefs = $indexdefs;
        foreach ($indexdefs as $name => $column) {
            $this->indexes[$name] = $this->makeIndex($column);
        }
    }

    function makeIndex($column)
    {
        $index = array();
        foreach ($this->array as $k => $v) {
            $index[$v[$column]] = $k;
        }
        return $index;
    }

    function get($key, $index=null)
    {
        $datapk = ($index===null) ? $key : $this->indexes[$index][$key];
        return $this->array[$datapk];
    }

    function getIndex($index)
    {
        return $this->indexes[$index];
    }

    function getData()
    {
        return $this->array;
    }
    function indexedBy($index)
    {
        $indexed = array();
        $indexedcolumn = $this->indexdef[$index];
        foreach ($this->indexes[$index] as $indexk => $arrayk) {
            $newarray = $this->array[$arrayk];
            unset($newarray[$indexedcolumn]);
            $indexed[$indexk] = $newarray;
        }
        return $indexed;
    }

    function sortedBy(/*multisort args*/)
    /* with strings converted to arrays corresponding to index of same name */
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach ($args as $n => $arg) {
            if (is_string($arg)) {
                $args[$n] = array_keys($this->indexes[$arg]);
            }
        }
        $sorted = $this->array;
        $args[] = $sorted;
        call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
        return $sorted;
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
$dataidx = new MultiIndex($data, array('id'=>'product_id', 'disp'=>'display_order'));
var_export($dataidx->sortedBy('disp', SORT_STRING, SORT_ASC));
var_export($dataidx->indexedBy('id'));
var_export($dataidx->get('samgal3', 'id'));
```

This should be a very basic base to build upon, and should be fine for small arrays. For simplicity's sake `MultiIndex`'s data is immutable and keys are always array indexes. Some obvious ways to enhance this are:

1. Make the `$indexdefs` accept a callable which returns a key for an item, instead of just a string/int naming an array key. This allows you to create indexes on any shape of data and even to create indexes which don't correspond to the data directly. (E.g., index by number of characters in the display name, or by the date+time of an array that keeps date and time separate, etc.)
2. Remove the requirement that an index key have only a single value. (Right now all indexes you make are assumed to be unique.)
3. Allow you to declare a `SORT_*` datatype for an index and have it automatically included in the arguments to `array_multisort` in `MultiIndex::sortedBy()`.
4. Include sparse indexes: if you have very common or very rare values, or just have a very large dataset and you want to save memory, you can make it so only certain values are indexed. If an item isn't found in an index, fall back to a full scan of unindexed items in the data.
5. Add [sensible interface implementations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php).
6. Allow the `MultiIndex` to have multiple backends, so you can have multiple indexes on any array-like structure (e.g. a dbm key-value store, a cloud store like DynamoDB, memcached, etc), and manipulate them all with the same object interface.
7. Make `MultiIndex` hold mutable data and update indexes incrementally and automatically as the data changes.

I'll keep this code on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/favila/5306999) for easy forking.

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.php.net/usort to generate a custom user defined sort.

Example:

```
<?php
//added a few more values
$data = array(
    0 => array('product_id'=>'samgal3',   'display_name' => 'Samsung Galaxy 3'),
    1 => array('product_id'=>'motorazrh', 'display_name' => 'Motorola Razr HD'),
    2 => array('product_id'=>'a', 'display_name' => 'a'),
    3 => array('product_id'=>'c', 'display_name' => 'c'),
    4 => array('product_id'=>'d', 'display_name' => 'd'),
    5 => array('product_id'=>'b', 'display_name' => 'b'),
    6 => array('product_id'=>'q', 'display_name' => 'q'),
    7 => array('product_id'=>'f', 'display_name' => 'f'),
);

function cmp($a,$b){
    return strcasecmp($a['display_name'],$b['display_name']);
}

usort($data,'cmp');
var_export($data);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/3mY8nU